# React - is it good practice to name an onClick function ...Handler if it is just a callback passed down?

Tags: reactjs

I see it is good practice to call a onClick handler somenameHandler. I like that.

Is is good practice to do that even if the handler is actually just a callback function passed down from a higher order component?

Comment: Does the intermediate handler do anything special like pass a prop value to the parent, such as an entity id or something?

Comment: no it just passes it on as is

Comment: I generally follow the naming `on` -> `handle`. <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}` for instance. If you are passing the function down through a few children I would just pass it straight though via `{... props}` spread on the component. Child then should just call it from props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to create an intermediate handler if you are just calling a parent prop. Just call it directly on click.

Answer (score 1):

overall declaring `somenameHandler` then assigning to onClick as `onClick={somenameHandler}` is interesting since when you declare directly as `onClick={() => { ...do stuff }}` on every component render you would be creating a new function in memory.

on the other hand, if you already receive that function via props, and you need no adaptation to it, I don't see merits to rename it. I would pass down directly as `onClick={this.props.somenameHandler}`. it makes the code clearer from my perspective.